# dynamic change of subcategory select options according to option selected in this subcategory

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

What i have now:
1)31june.html
2)32june.php

I have a table "jewelry" with this structure:

> > id
> >     brand(varchar)
> >     type(varchar)
> >     model(varchar)
> >     collection(varchar)
> >     description(text)
> >     code(varchar)
> >     url(varchar)
> >     available(int)

First file 31june.html is a select box in which are listed types (earrings,necklace,watches), according to which type we choose the script will send the selected type to second file 32june.php.

32june.php will do another things:

1)query :

```
$sql='SELECT collection FROM jewelry WHERE type = ?'
```

2) echo another select box with query($sql) in it.

For example i have chosen in select box earrings, in DB jewelry table  will be selected all collection with type earrings and this collection will be displayed in a new select box as an option.

What i want: i need to choose the type then the select box with collection will display according to type then I want to choose the collection in the generated select box and according to it, replace it  (this collection name) with another select option or for example with the new result i want to display in this select box.

For example:
Type: earrings -> generated select box with collection option value coll1
I select coll1.
I want coll1 to be replaced with the new date.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#type').on("change",function () {
        var chosen= $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "31june.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "chosen="+chosen,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $("#ajdiv2").html(response);
            },
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="ajdiv">
    <select name="type" id="type">
        <option>Select Type</option>         
        <option value="earrings">Earrings</option>
        <option value="necklace">Necklace</option>
        <option value="watches">Watches</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="ajdiv2"></div>

<?php
$chosen = $_POST['chosen'];

function mm ($chosen){

    $host="xxxx";

    $pass="xxxx";

    $user="xxxx";

    $db="xxxx";

    $connect ="mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db";

    $pdo = new PDO($connect, $user, $pass);

    $sql1='SELECT collection FROM jewelry WHERE type = ?';  

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql1); 

    $stmt->execute(array($chosen));

    foreach($stmt as $val){

        $select = '
            <select name="users" id="yol" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select Collection:</option>
            <option value="collection">
        ' . $val['collection'] . '</option>
        </select>';            
        echo $select;   
    }   
}
echo mm($chosen);
```

Comment: guys need your help xD

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with your loop, you are creating multiple select elements. Try changing to :

```
$select = '
        <select name="users" id="yol" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select Collection:</option>
';

foreach($stmt as $val){

    $select = $select . '
        <option value="collection">
    ' . $val['collection'] . '</option>';            
}

$select = $select . '</select>';
echo $select;
```

Then you can implement showUser(), or create another change handler for it instead like you have for type.

Comment: Sorry for stup qu but where to put new script and handler in the same files?

Comment: You could put them in the HTML file because it is ajaxed. If you do that and you are using the jQuery change handler then you have to create the handler _after_ the new HTML is added to the DOM.